Each symmetry of a triangle corresponds to exactly one permutation
I am trying to understand a statement about symmetries of a triangle. The set of lecture notes I am working through assert that (1) every permutation corresponds to a symmetry and (2) every symmetry corresponds to exactly one permutation.
As there are only six symmetries, I can write out each of them and directly verify this, but I would like to understand it at more of an abstract level. Once I generalize to an $n$-gon, I know that it is no longer the case that every permutation corresponds to a symmetry. (For example, there are $4! = 24$ permutations of four vertices but only $8$ symmetries of a square.)
For the second assertion, I believe the explanation in Dummit and Foote works, provided that I fully understand it. Say we label the vertices of an $n$-gon modulo $n$, so vertex $1$ is adjacent to vertices $2$ and $n-1$, moving clockwise. Because a symmetry is a rigid motion, it needs to map adjacent vertices to adjacent vertices, so if it sends vertex $1$ to vertex $i$, it needs to send vertex $2$ to either vertex $i+1$ or $i - 1$. Once this vertex is chosen, the new position of vertex $n-1$ is determined and the symmetry itself is fully determined.
I think this should imply that if $x$ and $y$ are distinct symmetries, then they correspond to distinct permutations of the vertices. But I think my logic is a bit circular here, as I'm inclined to define "distinct symmetries" as there existing a vertex sent to distinct places by the two symmetries.

This is a direct consequence of Cayley's theorem, which (roughly speaking) states that every group acting on a set with $n$ elements is isomorphic to a subgroup of the permutation group on $n$ elements. For a triangle, the symmetry group acts on $3$ elements and has $6$ elements, and also, there are $6$ permutations of $3$ elements, so they must be the same. It also immediately follows that the correspondence cannot hold for $n > 3$.

Let's restrict ourselves to regular $n$-gons (in general, a polygon has only the trivial symmetry).
It's straightforward to show that the symmetries form a group which we will call $D_n$. Every symmetry takes a side of the polygon to one of the $n$ sides of the polygon, possibly reversing it's orientation. No distinct symmetries have the same action on a side of the polygon, so there are $2n$ elements in $D_n$.
For the triangle, this means that $D_3$ has six elements. However, there are only two groups of order $6$, the cylic group $C_6$ and the permutation group $S_3$. It can be shown that $D_3$ isn't cyclic (because of the reflection/rotation distinction), so $D_3$ has to be isomorphic to $S_3$.
This means every permutation of 3 elements corresponds uniquely to a symmetry of an equilateral triangle.
